# If Affinity on Windows is set on 1 thread only, does it eliminate problems with thread-unsafe software?

Tags: windows, threads, hyper-threading, affinity, multi-threaded

Say I have a third party software executable I can't really edit or alter in anyway or debug properly. I suspect it has issues with multithreading in a way that it segfaults the application due to thread unsafe portions of it. Would setting the Affinity of the executable in Windows to a single thread only eliminate such issues, or only diminish them or do nothing at all due to other reasons?

Comment: just fyi, what you mean is "setting the affinity of the process to a single CPU." The process creates one or more threads, regardless of the affinity setting. The threads run, or not, on CPUs.

Answer (score 1):

It will reduce the probability of the issue occurring, but because two threads of the same process will not be scheduled in a particular order, it cannot provide “proven” safety.

While the scheduler is of course deterministic, the process in question won’t be the only process running. As such, you cannot say for certain what will happen. A simple mouse movement may lead to more work being scheduled.

However, you’re starting from mere speculation. Contact the maker with details on the crash and perhaps they can help you.